# The order of a conjugacy class of some element is equal to the index of the centralizer of that element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was reading at these [notes](http://lincoln.sjfc.edu/%7Egwildenberg/abstract_algebra/conjugacy-centralizer.pdf) and they said that

> The order of a conjugacy class of some element is equal to the index of the centralizer of that element.

My question is why they stated "some element" like this because of identity element or there is more element other than identity that this equation does not hold.

For example, I looked at $S_3$ and I saw it works for most of the elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This holds for all elements, and is a consequence of the [Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem).

Let $G$ act on its elements by conjugation. Then the orbit of an arbitrary element $g$ is the size of its conjugacy class, and the stabilizer of $g$ under this action is $C_{G}(g)$.

Comment: Corrected me if I am wrong. I think its not work for identity. since the conjugate class of identity in $S_3$ is $S_3$ again the centralizer of identity is again $S_3$ Hence the index is 1 not 6. where is my wrong.thanks

Comment: @henry The conjugacy class of the identity consists of the identity alone, so is of order $1$. The centralizer of the identity is the whole group, which is of index $1$. $1=1$.

Comment: thanks. now I am happy. thanks for correctness.